# How to use roots classes in all namespaces automatically with spl_autoload?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, spl

It is possible to make accessible a *Class* within `spl_autoload_register` (automatically)?

For example, I using `spl_autoload_register` in index.php:

```
<?php
class Utils {
   public function example() {
      echo 'Hello word!';
   }
}

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    $relative_class = strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class));

    $file = './src/' . $relative_class . '.php';

    if (is_file($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
});

$user = new \Controllers\Foo\User;
```

This `new \Controllers\Foo\User;` autoload this file *./src/controllers/foo/user.php*

user.php:

```
<?php
namespace Controllers/Foo;

class User
{
    public function foo() {
        //Something...
    }
}
```

If I need to use a *Utils class* I'll have to add `new \Controllers\Foo\User` in the file *user.php* like this:

```
public function foo() {
   \Utils::example();
}
```

or

```
<?php
namespace Controllers/Foo;

use \Utils as Utils;

class User
{
    public function foo() {
        Utils::example();
    }
}
```

It is possible to make accessible to **Utils class** within `spl_autoload_register` (automatically)? I would use without `use \Utils as Utils;` and without backslash (`\Utils::`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard anything to do this besides using `use ... as ...` or "backslash" (`\`), however we can *"cheat the PHP"* using `eval()` within the `spl_autoload_register()` to extend the *Utils class* within the `namespace`.

> Only use this if really necessary, prefer to use "backslash" (`\`) or `use \Utils as Utils`

Example (read comments in code):

```
<?php
class Utils {
   public static function example() {
      echo 'Hello World!';
   }
}

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    $relative_class = strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class));

    $file = './src/' . $relative_class . '.php';

    if (is_file($file)) {
        $np = explode('\\', $class); //Dividi string

        //Check if class exists in namespace (prevent conflicts)
        if (class_exists(implode('::', $np)) === false) {

            //Remove "class name", use only "namespace"
            array_pop($np);

            //evaluate a namespace in eval (extends the Utils class)
            eval(
                'namespace ' . implode('\\', $np) . ' {' . PHP_EOL .
                'class Utils extends \Utils {}' . PHP_EOL .
                '}'
            );
        }

        require_once $file;
    }
});

$user = new \Controllers\Foo\User;
$user->foo(); //Show "Hello word!"
```

I admit that it is **an ugly hack** and maybe I will not use, but it's still a hint yes.

> **Note:** `use \Utils as Utils` not work in `eval`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That's the whole point of using namespaces. You can reference a class whitout backslash or `use` statement **only** if it is in the same namespace you are using it. You can't hack the autoloader to automagically import the target class into the current namespace changing its namespace on the fly.

If your class doesn't belong to a *named* namespace, then it is in the **global** namespace and you still have to use with `\` or `use`. The same for `import` or `use` keywords in python, java, go, .net, c/c++, etc.